# convert string to float array in csv using tf.data

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I have a csv like this :

```
kw_text,kw_text_weight
amazon google,0.5 0.5
google facebook microsoft,0.5 0.3 0.2
```

| kw_text | kw_text_weight |
| --- | --- |
| amazon google | 0.5 0.5 |
| google facebook microsoft | 0.5 0.3 0.2 |

I want to convert column `text_weight` to `tf.data` . But I find nothing about it in tensorflow document website .

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you want:

```
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf

d = {"kw_text": [['amazon', 'google'], ['google', 'facebook', 'microsoft']], 
     "kw_text_weight": [['0.5', '0.5'], ['0.5', '0.3', '0.2']]}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)

# Convert string to float
for i in range(len(df.index)):
    df['kw_text_weight'][i] = [float(s) for s in df['kw_text_weight'][i]]

# Build dataset
rt=tf.ragged.constant(df['kw_text_weight'].tolist())
kw_text_weight_data = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(rt)

for feature_batch in kw_text_weight_data:
    print(feature_batch)
```

Outputs:

```
tf.Tensor([0.5 0.5], shape=(2,), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor([0.5 0.3 0.2], shape=(3,), dtype=float32)
```

Comment: I can't use ```pandas``` because the csv is too large to load it in memory ...

Comment: @DachuanZhao If you can't load csv file all at once, then slice it to small pieces and processing before convert it to dataset, if you have problem with big data then make another question or edit this question more specifically